# can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

While running a rails app, I am getting the following error -

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Support for Rails < 4.1.0 will be dropped. (called from warn at /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/forwardable.rb:183)
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/signalfx-0.1.0/lib/signalfx/conf.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:314:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.3. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
```

In the gemfile, I have the entry: `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3'`

Checking which gem is installed:

```
$ gem list|grep mysql2

activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
mysql2 (0.4.3)
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your Gemfile specifying the exact version

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.20'
```

then run

`bundle update mysql2`

This should update your `mysql2` gem with version from Gemfile

Comment: I doesn't, the version still remains 0.4.3

Comment: @user2851669 What if you set in Gemfile the exact version like `gem  'mysql2', '0.3.20'` and again run `bundle update mysql2`

Comment: Yes that works, Thanks :) Could you include it in your answer, so that I can accept it

Comment: Works for me too with 0.3.20 version. Thanks for the need.

Answer (score 0):

Often this can be avoided by prefixing your commands with `bundle exec` - which will ensure that the command is run in the context of the bundled gems, not the system gems.

This can occur if you're doing `bundle install` for multiple projects but not setting a deployment path or otherwise separating the installed gems for individual projects.

e.g. `bundle exec rails s`